# A question on the existence of an equation about non-autonomous semigroup

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-equations, semigroup-of-operators

In functional analysis, let $A$ be the infinitesimal generator of a $C_{0}$-semigroup $S(t)$ on a real Hilbert space $\mathbb{H}$, then the following properties are satisfied:

1. $\forall h \in \mathbb{H}$, $\int_{s}^{t} S(u)hdu \in \mathcal{D}(A)$, the domain of $A$; and $A\left(\int_{s}^{t} S(u)hdu\right) = S(t)h - S(s)h.$
2. $\forall h \in \mathbb{H}$, $S(t)h - S(s)h = \int_{s}^{t} AS(u) h du$.

In above, $A$ is time-independent, now I would like to consider a non-autonomous situation. Consider the family of operators $\{A(t): 0\leq t \leq T\}$ of linear operators such that

I. The domain $\mathcal{D}(A)$ of $A(t)$ is dense in $\mathbb{H}$ and independent of time $t$;

II. $\forall t \in [0, T]$, the resolvent $R(\lambda, A(t))$ exists for all $\lambda$ with $Re\lambda \geq 0$ and there exists $K > 0$ so that $\Vert R(\lambda, A(t)) \Vert \leq \frac{K}{(1+\vert \lambda \vert)}$;

III. There exists $0 < \delta \leq 1$ and $K > 0$ such that $\Vert (A(t) - A(s))A^{-1}(\tau) \Vert \leq K \vert t - s \vert^{\delta}$ for all $t,s,\tau \in [0, T]$;

IV. $\forall t \in [0, T]$ and some $\lambda \in \rho(A(t))$, the resolvent set of $A(t)$, the resolvent $R(\lambda, A(t))$, is a compact operator.

then $A(t)$ generates a unique linear evolution system $U(t,s), 0 \leq s \leq t \leq T$ which has the following properties:

a. $U(t,s)$ is compact if $t>s$;

b. $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}U(t,s) = A(t)U(t,s)$ if $t > s$.

My problems are as follows:

1). In the autonomous case, is Statement 2 a consequence of Statement 1?

2). For the non-autonomous case, for any $h \in \mathbb{H}$, is the following equation valid:

$U(t, s)h - h = \int_{s}^{t} (A(u) U(u,s) h) du$.

Or one can just do the integral on both sides of $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}U(t,s) = A(t)U(t,s)$ to get $U(t, s)h - h = \int_{s}^{t} (A(u) U(u,s) h) du$.

Thank you so much!! I would really appreciate it if any comments, answers or reference could be provided.

Comment: Statement 2 is not true in general. you need $h\in D(A)$ to ensure $S(u)h\in D(A)$.

Comment: @S.Maths Thank you for the comments! Actually, I may miss to mention that under the assumption I - III, the evolution system $U(t,s)$ maps $\mathbb{H}$ into $\mathcal{D}(A)$, so I guess that this is not an issue. May I ask under this condition is the second argument correct please? (like it is just a integral on both sides.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) In the autonomous case, the statement
$$2.\; \forall h \in \mathbb{H},\; S(t)h - S(s)h = \int_{s}^{t} AS(u) h\,du \quad (*),$$
is not true in general. You need that $S(u)h\in \mathcal{D}(A)$.

If we assume that $S(u)$ map $\mathbb{H}$ into $\mathcal{D}(A)$, then $(*)$ follows by integrating, from $s$ to $t$, the following equality
$$\frac{d}{du} S(u)h=AS(u)h.$$
You can conclude Statement 2 from Statement 1, but you need the following lemma:

> If $f$ solves the Cauchy problem (classically) and $A$ is a closed operator, then
> $$\int_{s}^{t} f(u)\,du \in \mathcal{D}(A) \qquad \text{and} \qquad A\left(\int_{s}^{t} f(u)\,du\right)=\int_{s}^{t} Af(u)\,du.$$

(2) In the non-autonomous case, the same argument applies.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You are definitely correct, but I just find something in Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators by Tosio Kato. Consider Chapter IX. "perturbation theory for semigroups of operators" Section 5, Theorem 1.19. In its proof, under the formula (1.45), it says that "if h $\in$ $\mathcal{D}(A)$, then $AS(s)h = -\frac{d}{ds}S(s)h$ and hence $\int_{r}^{t}AS(s)hds = S(r)h - S(t)h$. Recall the definition and the closedness of $A$, we may write this as $A \int_{r}^{t} S(s) hds = (S(r) - S(t))h$". Based on this, it seems that the lemma you mentioned is not so necessary?

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: What you quoted from Kato's book is exactly what I said in the lemma. Also, I'm not requiring $h\in \mathcal{D}(A)$ as we might have $S(u)h\in \mathcal{D}(A)$ just for $h\in \mathbb{H}$ (e.g., for a differentiable semigroup). If you are satisfied with my answer you might accept it to close this topic.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and comments. I have one more little question: if $U(t,s)$ is as what I stated above and moreover, it is compact if $t-s > 0$, also, $U(t,s)$ maps $\mathbb{H}$ into $\mathcal{D}(A)$, can I conclude that $U(t,s)h - h = \int_{s}^{t}A(u)U(u,s)hdu$. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Compactness is not relevant here. In my answer, I said that the argument still hold for $U(t,s)$ (by integrating $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}U(t,s) = A(t)U(t,s)$)..

Comment: Actually, I feel that since $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}U(t,s) = A(t)U(t,s)$ is only valid when $t > s$, I guess that one can only apply integration over time intervals like $[s+\epsilon, t], \epsilon > 0$, which means $U(t,s)h - U(s+\epsilon,s)h = \int_{s+\epsilon}^{t} A(u)U(u,s)h du$. Then to get the case I want ($\epsilon = 0$), I guess I can take a limit or at least it is true that $<U(t,s)h - h, \zeta>_{\mathbb{H}} = \int_{s}^{t} <A(u)U(u,s)h, \zeta>_{\mathbb{H}}du$ with any fixed $\zeta \in \mathbb{H}$. Is this correct please?